# Form data will not post - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

The code I am using:

Angular side

```
vm.onSubmit =function(){
            var person = vm.formData.slice(0, 1)[0]; //This takes the required fields from the model object nested in an array.
                $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/register',
            data: person,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }});
```

Server side

```
        module.exports.registerPost = function (req,res){
       if(!req.body.email || !req.body.password){
           res.json({success: false, message: 'Please enter an email and password to register.'});
       } else {
           var newUser = new User({
               firstName: req.body.firstName,
               lastName: req.body.lastName,
               email: req.body.email,
               password: req.body.password
       });
```

The post sends, but I get the error that I haven't enter username or password. Everything else checks out. Doing the call with postman shows the server side is not the issue.

Comment: Your endpoint url looks like `api/register` where as your function has been named as `registerPost`.. Are you calling the right function?

Comment: @DavidR It's the correct function because I get the error message I coded into it as res.json.

Comment: Do you receive any error(s) in your developer console?

Comment: @Kalamarico I am unfamiliar with CORS. Pretty new to this all.

Comment: @DavidR No console errors, no.

Comment: Okay.. Can you please update your post with your `app.js` code where you have `expressjs` configuration?

Comment: check the request params & headers (with dev-tools network tab). run a test with postman, then with the angular app and see what the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.

It seems "data" in the $http object references the request.  I wrote it that way because I thought I had to modify the content-type on the headers, but apparently I didn't.

I changed my code to:

```
vm.onSubmit =function(){
        var person = vm.formData.slice(0, 1)[0];
            $http.post('api/register', person);
}}
```

And now it works just fine now.